# Why is the `sx` prop so much slower?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

As per MUI's own doco, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68383383/924597) - components using `sx` render significantly slower than components using other styling mechanisms.

On the surface, it looks like `sx` is just an alternate convenience API for doing the same thing - so I wouldn't expect it to have such a different performance profile.

My question is: *Why* is the rendering of a component using `sx` so much slower - what's it doing so differently?  Is it a whole different  styling engine or something?

I'm curious about the possibility of optimising it, or coming up with a compromise that retains most of the usability but omits whatever feature is causing the slowdown.

Please note, this question is about "why is the performance so different" - not "why do you think the difference doesn't matter".

Comment: Maybe the greatest hit in performance comes with how `sx` is used `sx={{color:'red'}}`. The problem here is that `{color:'red'}` object is re-created on each parent render, causing a child to re-render as well. Unless of course `sx` value is memoised somehow by MUI. Try wrapping the value in `useMemo` before passing it to `sx` property.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As I started to dig into this, I realized that I needed to measure the performance of different scenarios in order to have any confidence in my understanding of the performance aspects of the `sx` prop.

The performance information in the MUI documentation was gathered using benchmarks that can be found here: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/v5.13.2/benchmark/browser.

I believe an earlier version of those benchmarks was based on some variation of this repository: https://github.com/mnajdova/react-native-web. The react-native-web repo was used as a starting point because of its "benchmarks" package which contains a useful framework for measuring the performance of different React element rendering/styling approaches.

I created my own version here: https://github.com/ryancogswell/mui-style-benchmarks. You can use this as a starting point to dig into this further. Below are the measurements I made and my conclusions.

#### My Results for the "Mount deep tree" Benchmark

This test renders 639 elements with approximately 17 CSS properties each except for the cases ("..._minimal", "..._medium")
which reduce the number of CSS properties to show the performance impact.

| Styling Implementation | Time in ms | Implementation Desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| inline-styles | 22.78 | No styling engine, just use `style` prop |
| mui_sx_full | 36.89 | MUI Box `sx` prop with 17 CSS properties |
| mui_sx_medium | 24.09 | MUI Box `sx` prop with 9 CSS properties |
| mui_sx_minimal | 18.15 | MUI Box `sx` prop with 4 CSS properties |
| mui_styled_box | 22.38 | MUI `styled` MUI `Box` with 17 CSS properties |
| mui_styled_box_minimal | 17.90 | MUI `styled` MUI `Box` with 4 CSS properties |
| tss_react_makestyles | 17.10 | `makeStyles` from `tss-react` with 17 CSS properties |
| mui_styled | 16.93 | MUI `styled` `div` with 17 CSS properties |
| mui_styled_minimal | 13.77 | MUI `styled` `div` with 4 CSS properties |
| emotion_styled | 16.69 | Emotion `styled` `div` with 17 CSS properties |
| emotion_styled_minimal | 12.76 | Emotion `styled` `div` with 4 CSS properties |
| emotion_css | 12.58 | Emotion `css` `div` with 17 CSS properties |

#### Conclusions

- MUI `styled` (e.g. `import {styled} from '@mui/material/styles'`) only adds a small amount of overhead
  to Emotion's `styled`.
- tss-react performs similarly to MUI `styled`.
- Emotion `styled`, Emotion `css`, MUI `styled`, and the MUI `sx` prop are all more expensive when there are
  more CSS properties passed to the styling engine.
- The performance of the `sx` prop degrades more quickly than the `styled` API as more
  CSS properties are passed to it. With 17 CSS properties the performance is much worse than the `styled` API (2x).
- The `sx` prop performs just fine for a small number (e.g. < 5) of CSS properties. Particularly, if you
  are already using a MUI component in a given situation, there is no meaningful performance difference
  between wrapping it with `styled` or using the `sx` prop if you are just using a small number
  of CSS properties.

#### What is the cause of the `sx` prop slowness?

> Is it a whole different styling engine or something?

It is not a different styling engine. The output of the work done for the `sx` prop is fed into the `styled` API of the main styling engine (e.g. Emotion or styled-components); so using the `sx` prop with the `Box` component is guaranteed to be slower than the equivalent styles using `styled` on a `div` because the `sx` prop still uses `styled` in the end but does additional work first.

##### What is the additional work done by the `sx` prop?

- The MUI `styled` API [calls styleFunctionSx](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.5.3/packages/mui-system/src/createStyled.js#L167) in order to transform the CSS properties in the `sx` prop to the form expected by the styling engine.
- `styleFunctionSx` [traverses all the CSS properties](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.5.3/packages/mui-system/src/styleFunctionSx/styleFunctionSx.js#L66) in the `sx` prop
- For each CSS property, it checks to see if it has a [style function](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.5.3/packages/mui-system/src/styleFunctionSx/styleFunctionSx.js#L36) for transforming the prop value. These style functions provide support for shorthand notation for some properties such as [padding and margin](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.5.3/packages/mui-system/src/spacing.js#L209) and support for using theme spacing units instead of pixel values.
- Each of the style functions leverages the [style function](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.5.3/packages/mui-system/src/style.js#L31) in https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.5.3/packages/mui-system/src/style.js to handle some common transformations of prop values including the support for [breakpoint-specific values](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.5.3/packages/mui-system/src/style.js#L64).

The net effect is that for each CSS property there are a number of lookups and function calls to see if the CSS property needs to be transformed even in the cases where the value passes through without changes.

> I'm curious about the possibility of optimising it, or coming up with a compromise that retains most of the usability but omits whatever feature is causing the slowdown.

I'm sure that performance improvements are possible for the `sx` prop, but I don't think there is any single silver bullet for easily making it faster. Instead it will probably require a large number of little changes that are each barely measurable, but cumulatively provide decent improvement. The challenge is to make those changes without simultaneously making the code more complex and/or harder to maintain and/or more error prone.

The main compromise that "retains most of the usability" is to use Emotion's [css prop](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop) directly. It can be used directly on elements in a similar fashion as the `sx` prop -- you just lose the shorthand notations and theme lookups that the `sx` prop provides. The theme lookups (e.g. for colors or spacing units) are easy to get directly from the theme by using the [useTheme hook](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop) in the component. The [theme.breakpoints API](https://mui.com/customization/breakpoints/#api) can be used instead of the breakpoint shorthands; though the `sx` breakpoint features are much nicer from a DX standpoint.

My personal approach is to use `tss-react` for most styles (this allowed for straightforward migration from the JSS-based `makeStyles/useStyles` while moving from v4 to v5) and then to use the `sx` prop for some one-off styles on components that only appear a small number of times on a given page.

Comment: I was tempted to do the same but read this in the tss doc "I would not recommend using the Sx syntax in tandem with TSS, as its benefits do not seem significant in this context.". However, I'm not sure I understand the argument that follows.

Comment: @AlexandreAnnic That page in the TSS docs (https://docs.tss-react.dev/mui-sx-syntax) seems to be referring to using sx-style shorthands (e.g. for colors) within TSS styles and is not saying anything about use of the `sx` prop on MUI components in projects that happen to also be using TSS.

Comment: is there a difference in terms of performance between these two options ? `<Box css={{ marginTop: 2 }}></Box>` vs `import { css } from '@emotion/react'; <Box css={css\` margin-top: 16px; \`}></Box>`

Comment: @RegarBoy Did you mean to use `sx` instead of `css` on the first option? If so, I would expect the second option to be slightly faster, but unless you are using other features of `Box`, in the second option you can improve performance a little further by using `<div>` instead of `<Box>`.

Comment: @RyanCogswell No, I didn't mean to use `sx` in the first option I know it's less performant than `css`, I wonder if there's any significant difference between assigning an object with camelCase properties to `css` prop versus a className generated by `css` import from '@emotion/react'.

Comment: @RegarBoy If you didn't mean to use `sx`, then I wouldn't expect `marginTop: 2` to work. I don't think Emotion will convert that to `16px` -- that's part of the `sx` functionality in MUI. I would guess that there's a tiny performance difference between using object styles vs. string styles with Emotion, but I would expect that difference to be negligible (small enough to not matter in any practical way) and significantly less than the impact of using `Box` instead of `<div>`, and I don't know which approach would be faster.