# MUI - extending sx props to memorize value and avoid rerenders

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, react-usememo, sx

The `sx` prop from **MUI** is useful for speed and code readability (in reason) but it can cause many unnecessary re-renders (and this compounds with the `sx` [lesser performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71596050/why-is-the-sx-prop-so-much-slower)).

So I was wandering if there was a way to add a useMemo wrapped version of the MUI `sx` props. How would I go about extending MUI to achieve this?

Here a simplified example of what I mean.

Bases situation:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  return
    <>
      <Box sx={{color: "red"}}> I am a bit static </Box>
      <Box sx={{width: window.innerWidth + "px"}}> I am so dynamic! </Box>
    </>  
};
```

This would be the (in this case excessive) optimisation:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const boxStyle = useMemo(() => ({color: "red"}), [])

  return
    <>
      <Box sx={boxStyle}> I am a bit static </Box>
      <Box sx={{width: window.innerWidth + "px"}}> I am so dynamic! </Box>
    </>  
};
```

This is the "api" I want to achieve by extending MUI:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  return
    <>
      <Box sxm={{color: "red"}}> I am a bit static </Box>
      <Box sx={{width: window.innerWidth + "px"}}> I am so dynamic! </Box>
    </>  
};
```

How I would go about creating this `useMemo` augmented version of `sx`, readily availably in any MUI component?

I have seen [this package](https://github.com/andywer/use-inline-memo). It could be a step in the good direction.

Comment: I realise maybe the scope of my question is wrong. Trying to extend MUI is too hard and a reusable hook could do the job.

This is the closest I got to it.

Here the reusable hook:
`const sxm = (sxprop: SxProps) => {
  return { sx: useMemo(() => sxprop, []) };
};`

How to use it:
`<Box {...sxm({ width: 100, height: 100, border: "1px solid black" })}/>`
How can I make it even more concise?