# When should I use the styled API for styling instead of the sx prop? [Material-UI]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I'm working on converting an existing codebase to Material UI and am trying to set a standard going forward for how the components are styled.

I've previously worked in a codebase where all the components are styled using the `sx` prop and didn't notice any particular issues. However, I've seen it recommended in various places that the `sx` prop should only be used for 'one time' styling and that the `styled()` API would be a better choice if you need multiple components of the same type to have the same styling.

Although what I don't understand is why that is? If I created a component that was a wrapper around an inner Material UI component and the inner component had been styled with the `sx` prop. Wouldn't this also achieve the goal of having multiple components of the same type having the same styling? If so, what use is there for the 'styled()' API?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before `sx` was added to Material UI `styled()` was an easy and short syntax to create reuable Material UI components with different styling.

With `sx` you now can pretty much do everything like `styled()`, but better.

Some may argue, that requires significant more code to create reuable Material UI components using `sx`, which is true, but there are two things `sx` can do and `styled()` not:

1. can be conditional based on component state (different style for the component or different styles for different children)
2. has shorthands / helpers like `{ ml: 1 }` (spacing) or `{ display: { xl: 'block', xs: 'none' } }` (breakpoints)

Especially the last point is a big selling point for `sx`, because it makes it easier for your styled components be in sync with the MUI styling and theme.

`styled()` is still a good way to create styled reusable HTMLElements.

Me personally, use `sx` for everything, but styled reusable HTMLElements.

Comment: Okay thanks, that's a helpful answer. Are you aware of any performance differences between `styled()` and `sx`? I'd seen some comments around mentioning that `sx` performs worse as it outputs more HTML script tags but I'm not sure how accurate that is.

Comment: @GeorgeWalter `sx` is slower than `styled()`. Someone else did some research and benchmarks; see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71695686/315363

Based on these benchmarks, in my opinion, the overhead of `sx` is not significant for most use cases.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using `sx` over `props` like ` <Box display="flex" gap="16px">`