# If sx prop has such performance issues, should we use it sparingly ? And do dynamic and nested styles also impact it's performance?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, sx

As per an answer in this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71596050/why-is-the-sx-prop-so-much-slower#:~:text=The%20output%20of%20the%20work,in%20the%20end%20but%20does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71596050/why-is-the-sx-prop-so-much-slower#:%7E:text=The%20output%20of%20the%20work,in%20the%20end%20but%20does), sx prop's performance as compared to styled api decreases dramatically if number of css properties in sx prop starts becoming more than 5.

So should we use sx prop as sparingly as possible if our components are not using any theme properties or if many css properties are required for the component, and use the styled api instead ?

Also is the performance of sx prop affected with dynamic and nested styles as well ?