# What are the differences between <Div>, <StyledDiv>, and <Box sx={...}> in MUI?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

The MUI documentation has a table of benchmark cases [here](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/usage/#performance-tradeoffs). But the different cases aren't clear to me. Please explain what the differences are with real examples between the following:

1. `<Div>`
2. `<StyledDiv>`
3. `<Box sx={…}>`

I am assuming these correlate to:

1. `<Box>`
2. `<Box mb={2}>`
3. `<Box sx={{mb:2}>`

If this is correct and you are focusing on performance, then you should favor [system properties](https://mui.com/system/properties/) over the `sx` property. However, only a few MUI components support `system properties` while all support `sx`. This has led my team to using `Box` in combination with the `component` property thinking it is better for performance, 181ms instead of 296 ms. For example,

- Instead of `<Paper sx={{mb:2}}>`
- We use `<Box component={Paper} mb={2}>`

Inspecting the components using React Dev Tools, it seems like the system properties are converted directly into the `sx` property meaning my team's decision is not better for performance and does not correlate to `<StyledDiv>`.

[image: Box with system property]

The `Box` with `mb={2}` passed as a property in turn renders a `div styled` that has `mb:2` inside the `sx` property.

[image: Styled div with sx property]

It is also worth noting, that the `<Box component={Paper} mb={2}>` approach rather than `<Paper sx={{mb:2}}>` while it doesn't create additional DOM elements there are additional components.

[image: Box]

versus

[image: Paper]

So should you favor `system properties` over the `sx` property or not?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are examples of what the documentation means when referring to `Div`, `StyledDiv`, and `Box`.

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

function Div() {
  return <div>I'm a simple Div component</div>;
}
const StyledDiv = styled("div")`
  border: black solid 1px;
`;
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Div />
      <StyledDiv>I'm a StyledDiv</StyledDiv>
      <Box sx={{ border: "purple solid 1px" }}>I'm a Box</Box>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit benchmark component examples]

The differences in the benchmarks have nothing to do with using `sx` vs. system properties -- those are basically just two syntax alternatives for the same underlying functionality and I wouldn't expect any significant performance difference between the two. I would expect that wrapping other Material-UI components with `Box` in order to use system properties instead of `sx` would be worse performance than using `sx` on the initial Material-UI component (e.g. `Paper`).

Related answer: [Why is the `sx` prop so much slower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71596050/why-is-the-sx-prop-so-much-slower/71695686#71695686)

Comment: Very clear examples, thank you!